# Gstreamer command that displays and records a video to mp4

Tags: linux, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am new to gstreamer.  I am trying to write a command that displays a running video from source (e.g. webcam) and record the video to a mp4.

I have tried separately

`gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! autovideosink`

to display the video, and

`gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4`

to record the video.  Both commands behave as expected.  However, when I tried to combine the two using

`gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! tee name=t t. ! autovideosink t. ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4`

it does not work.  The display freezes and the mp4 produced has no value (0 byte).  I tried adding `queue` after the `tee` for each respective branch like

`gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! x264enc ! mp4mux ! filesink location=output.mp4`

but the problem persists.

How can I fix this?  Thank you

Comment: Please re-read the guidance for the tags you've used.  This is clearly a question about __using__ gstreamer, not about __programming__, so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.  It _might_ be suitable for [su]: consult the Help Centre for the site before you post.

Answer (score 1):

If HEVC is suitable for you you can use following pipeline

`gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc ! tee name=t ! queue ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! x265enc ! filesink location="output.mp4"`

I used videotestsrc since I don't have webcam.

Comment: thanks for trying to help.  I couldn't get v4l2src to connect with x265enc.  I got the error ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(3072): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstV4l2Src:v4l2src0:
streaming stopped, reason not-negotiated (-4) .